# Debugging Android in Eclipse; Source not found

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I just got eclipse to work and finished installing All the development tools for android


Everything works fine except when i try to debug my code 

 
I get source not foundin my ActivityThreat... window 
I can edit source lookup path but i wouldnt even know what im looking for. 


I had a previous problem with an '!' in the path of eclipse which caused eclipse to crash on startup (turns out windows vista allowed me to create a username with '!' in the name and then created a user folder on my computer with '!' which is in the path to my desktop.) 
Now that i moved eclipse to C:/ everything except debugging works fine.

Comment: If you were able to add a link to a zipped version of your project, it might be possible to work out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can unzip the android.jar file using a program like JD GUI. then you can link the file by clicking change attached source and pointing it to that file...
That allows you to then see the classes normally when debugging

Comment: Unfortunately after exporting the source I'm still not able to select it from the "Edit Source Lookup Path"